# Integrate unique registration method to prevent duplicate accounts

Tags: feature-request, registration

After a bit digging, it seems is very easy to create multiple accounts on Stack Overflow and start cheating with the reputation system. I believe so much in the SO rep system as an indication for developer knowledge (some people even embed their profile in their CVs), and feel proud of high rep score.

In order to keep SO clean, and keep the reputation system fair, should the SO registration procedure be modified to ensure that only one person can create one account and not more. Something like a digital fingerprint, sample quiz, or any other procedure to make it hard for someone to create multiple accounts.

**Note**: I am writing this because I know someone who did so.

Comment: If you know of a user that is sock puppeteering , than you should flag one of the user's posts with a custom moderator message explaining which accounts are involved and what you believe they are doing that is against the rules. You could also choose to write SE an email instead, especially if you want to write a lot. I downvoted since there are already systems in place to try to catch these users, and also many skilled users that are able to eventually figure out something weird is going on and to report it to SE for further investigation. No need to make signing up harder.

Comment: If only those damn Libertarians would stop torpedoing the efforts to create a World Government and associated International ID system... BTW, tangential topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange/57685#57685

Comment: If someone needs sock puppet accounts to get some score, their answers obviously aren't _that_ good, and they will get caught in the hiring process. If not, it's the company's loss to base hiring on SO score.

Comment: Reputation is only a very, very rough indication of any knowledge and should never be taken at face value.

Answer (score 8):

People who want to cheat the voting system by creating multiple accounts to vote for themselves (or ask softball questions for them to answer, or launder reputation to them via bounties) will find ways to do so. There's no foolproof way to enforce the creation of only one account per person.

Therefore, we have very good tools for detecting this kind of voting fraud, and it's reasonably easy for us to identify multiple accounts operated for this by a single user. Once we do so, all of their voting fraud that they took hours or days to set up can be undone in an instant, and they will have gained absolutely nothing from it. They may even find themselves completely blocked from accessing the site.

I think people would be shocked if they knew just how many incidents of voting fraud we clean up silently every day. We try to do our best to keep the voting system honest, and it takes some effort to hide significant voting fraud from us for more than a short duration.

The problem is not the creation of multiple accounts, it's using them to do things you could not do with a single account. A better use of developer time is in the improvement of voting fraud detection tools and automated handling of this by the system.